# averiguar cuantos elementos estan ocultos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datepicker, javascript-objeto

Hola llevo ya un rato intentando averiguar si hay alguna forma mas sencilla y entendible de hacer esto que la siguiente que he encontrado en los apuntes la cual no entiendo y ya he preguntado a mis compañeros y ninguno parece tener mucha idea, si hubiera una forma mas sencilla me gustaria conocerla por que para ser losprimeros ejercicios del tema lo veo muy exagerado tener que hacer una funcion asi con tan poca teoria

```
jQuery.expr.filters.hidden = function( elem ) {
    var width = elem.offsetWidth, height = elem.offsetHeight,
        skip = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "tr";

    // ¿el elemento posee alto 0, ancho 0 y no es un <tr>?
    return width === 0 && height === 0 && !skip ?

        // entonces debe estar oculto (hidden)
        true :

        // pero si posee ancho y alto y no es un <tr>
        width > 0 && height > 0 && !skip ?

            // entonces debe estar visible
            false :

            // si nos encontramos aquí, es porque el elemento posee ancho
            // y alto, pero además es un <tr>,
            // entonces se verifica el valor del estilo display
            // aplicado a través de CSS
            // para decidir si está oculto o no
            jQuery.curCSS(elem, "display") === "none";
};

jQuery.expr.filters.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !jQuery.expr.filters.hidden( elem );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Es mucho más sencillo, básicamente es echar mano del pseudo selector `:hidden`,

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  var hiddenElements = $('#container').find(':hidden');
  $('#console').html('Elementos ocultos:' + hiddenElements.length);
});
```

```css
.hide-me{
  display:none;
}

#console{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div class="hide-me">Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div class="hide-me">Div 4</div>
  <div>Div 5</div>
  <div class="hide-me">Div 6</div>
</div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @Borja Lorenzo? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a nuevos privilegios). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!